# all buttons on a store redirect to page not found

Tags: magento2.3, multistore

> **I'm using a multiple store**.
>
> **The first store works perfectly but the second one has an issue.**
>
> **when we click to a button (add to cart, create account, contact) it
>   redirects to 'error 404' page not found.)**

It's not my first time to create a multiple store, but I never had this error.

**I specify that i m using magento 2.3.2 (it was 1.9 before migration), php 7**

Help please

---

[2020-03-25 12:18:50] main.CRITICAL: Type de bloc invalide: Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): Type de bloc invalide: Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View at /home/teico/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:274, ReflectionException(code: 0): Class Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\CommentFactory does not exist at /home/teico/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:35, ReflectionException(code: 0): Class Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\CommentFactory does not exist at /home/teico/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:29)"} []

this is my system.log

---

[2020-03-25 12:31:26] main.DEBUG: URI '/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly90ZWljby5iZS9jYXRhbG9nc2VhcmNoL3Jlc3VsdC9pbmRleC8_cD0xJnE9ZmxleGlibGUlMkJpbm94JTJCMjYlMkIzNA,,/product/19541/'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add) [] []
[2020-03-25 12:31:26] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor" [] []
[2020-03-25 12:31:27] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.reviews' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-03-25 12:31:32] main.DEBUG: URI '/review/product/post/id/26046/'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post) [] []
[2020-03-25 12:31:32] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post\Interceptor" [] []
[2020-03-25 12:31:37] main.ERROR: Warning: file_put_contents(/home/teico/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---773_TRANSLATE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/teico/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 691 [] []
[2020-03-25 12:32:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-03-25 12:32:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00084185600280762,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1824,"realmem_start":48234496,"emalloc_start":45650072} [] []
[2020-03-25 12:32:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is run [] []
[2020-03-25 12:32:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00077104568481445,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":48234496,"emalloc_start":45652072} [] []
[2020-03-25 12:32:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is run [] []

this is debug.log

Comment: you are using ngnix or apache ?

Comment: I'm using apache

Comment: can you share url ?

Comment: is their any way to share this with you in private? because I'm not the owner of the website

Comment: i dont know if you can msg me here but you can share a link here if you want

Comment: can you check var/log/ system and debug log ?

Comment: do you want me to copy tadays log?

Comment: tail -f execption.log and tail -f debug.log in command line

Comment: please paste few line

Comment: check the code below please

Comment: do you run magento provision commands and flush cache ?

Comment: sorry i don't get your question!

Comment: do you run bin/magento setup:upgrade di compile and clear cache?

Comment: yes I did this morning, but not now:php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105939/discussion-between-yasir-latif-and-nouari-zineb).

Comment: I' m talking to you in the chat! are you there?